# PHP Menu Side by side listing

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I have unknow lenght php array. I want to side by side listing. I want for or while loop.

For example;

$menu[9]=...;

My incorrect code:

```
<?php
$m=ceil($s/7);
for($i=0;$i<$m;$i++){
?>
<div class="cat-left-drop-menu-left">
<ul>
<?php
for($z=0;$z<7;$z++){
?>
<li><a href="#"><?php echo $altmenu[$z] ;?></a></li>
<?php } ?>
</ul>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

i want this output:

```
<div class="cat-left-drop-menu-left">

<ul>
<li><a href="#">$menu[1]</a></li>
<li><a href="#">$menu[2]</a></li>
<li><a href="#">$menu[3]</a></li>
<li><a href="#">$menu[4]</a></li>
<li><a href="#">$menu[5]</a></li>
<li><a href="#">$menu[6]</a></li>
<li><a href="#">$menu[7]</a></li>
</ul>

</div>

<div class="cat-left-drop-menu-left">

<ul>
<li><a href="#">$menu[8]</a></li>
<li><a href="#">$menu[9]</a></li>
</ul>

</div>
```

It should be in the loop.

foreaxample:

```
1  8
2  9
3
4
5
6
7
```

Comment: You question is not very clear, could you provide an example of what you are trying to achieve or try and clear your answer up better?

Comment: i have one-dimensional array. I want to list side by side. for example: $menu= array("1", "2", "3","4","5","6","7","8","9"); i want column.

Comment: no it does not work.

Comment: @Anant i need for in for loop

Comment: why? check tis screen shot:-  1.http://prntscr.com/cb48o6   2. http://prntscr.com/cb48tr   3. http://prntscr.com/cb48fs ... also `foreach` take care of indexes so better than `for` or `while` loop.

Comment: @AllenButler I've corrected the question

Comment: @GökselTığlı Good, but now I need to see the PHP arrays you are trying to loop through. Also, it would be convenient to see the output you are currently receiving.

Comment: @AllenButler array as $altmenu=array("1", "2", "3","4","5","6","7","8","9");